# How do you force a mat-dialog to close in an Angular test?

Tags: angular, jasmine, modal-dialog, karma-jasmine, angular-material2

**Scenario :**

- I have a component which is a wrapper around another component, and the wrapper component calls `this.dialog.open(otherComponent)`.
- In the 'it creates' test for the wrapper component, the dialog pops
  open in the test browser, and remains there for the duration of the
  test suite, obscuring everything underneath it and even the test
  results.

  - How do I force it to close?
  - I've tried `dialog.close(),
    dialog.closeAll(),` I've tried creating a mock dialog and closing
    that, but nothing seems to work because the original component under
    testing does not close that dialog.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You should mock it, you're not supposed to rely on a library when you unit test your components. In interface testing, simply simulate a click in the backdrop or the closing button, or a keypress on Esc.

Comment: As I said, I've tried mocking it. Will try the esc.

Comment: You've tried but you still have the dialog popping in your tests. So don't try, succeed !

Comment: Okay, I'll keep trying! :)

Comment: You were correct, I was mocking MatDialogRef but not MatDialog!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 {provide: MatDialog, useValue: {}}
```

I had mocked MatDialogRef in this manner, but not MatDialog. Thanks @trichetriche for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I created to create a new mock of the dialog service if you want :

```
matDialogMock(): SpyObj<MatDialog> {
    return createSpyObj<MatDialog>('MatDialog', {
      open: {
        afterOpened: () => of(undefined),
        afterClosed: () => of(undefined),
      } as any
    });
  }
```

By calling

```
const mock = matDialogMock();
```

You create a new instance of the mock and can inject it into your tests.

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you.